# CMake: Automatic Boost download and build if not found

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I would like to have a failsafe setup in my project. I don't really want to mess around with installing boost and the other libs every time we are setting stuff up.

So it would be awesome, that if a required Boost version is not found, cmake downloads and compiles boost and uses that version for the project.

Is there an easy possibility?

I found [this](https://github.com/maidsafe/MaidSafe/blob/next/cmake_modules/add_boost.cmake) in the maid-safe project. But I am not that experienced with cmake and have no clue how to use it.

Comment: That's the way to go, for a project that doesn't offer reliable cmake build. It's easier if the project is CMake based already, you can use [ExternalProject_Add](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html). Here's a [trivial example](https://github.com/oblitum/operations) that grabs gmock/gtest from system directory but can easily changed to download them from web.

Comment: Check out `ExternalProject_Add` which should allow you to download the source code of boost and build it. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: BTW, The looking at the cmake link you posted maid-safe project uses ExternalProject_Add to build boost so you have an example..

Comment: I know, that's why I posted that example, but it does not look easy at all to use it. Isn't there just a maven-like way to resolve dependencies?

Comment: I would just spend 1 hour and learn how to use ExternalProject_Add. Other methods will be more work on your part.

Comment: but to do something like this should be a common task, I really have to do it on my own? I do really miss maven currently... (Of course maven has its own flaws)

Comment: That is why `ExternalProject_Add` was created.

Comment: the effort you have to learn maven is comparable, it's just not maven. If you want to stick to maven better go java.

Comment: Okay, if i decide to implement this, I will post it as answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [this](https://gist.github.com/thiagowfx/970e3931387ed7db9a39709a8a130ee9) **find module** I created.

1. Download the [FindBoost.cmake](https://gist.github.com/thiagowfx/970e3931387ed7db9a39709a8a130ee9) file.
2. Save it somewhere within your project; for example, in a directory named `cmake`.
3. Add the aforementioned directory to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Here's one way of accomplishing this: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)`.
4. Set `BOOST_REQUESTED_VERSION`. For example, `set(BOOST_REQUESTED_VERSION 1.61)`.
5. Use the module like you would do with any other find module. For instance: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system program_options)`

If **Boost** is not installed in your system it will be **downloaded and compiled on-the-fly**, at build time (i.e., when you run `make`). If it is installed in your system, nothing will be downloaded.

(**Optional**) You can change `BOOST_ROOT_DIR` to  the root directory of the location where boost is installed in your system. This is useful if it is installed in a non-standard location.

Comment: Errors with the following message: 1> CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
1> Missing variable is:
1> CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES

Comment: Same problem with CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES in end 2022 unfortunately (cmake 3.20)

Comment: For those reading this in 2023: an updated FindBoost.cmake can be found here https://gist.github.com/paolostefan/d7db4f6a575da0843b4f346272907d81 - it downloads the proper file, distinguishes between WIN32 and the rest of the world, and finds the include dir. Untested for non-include-only Boost components